# How to resize all icons on the desktop

Tags: 18.04, icons, resize

I suddenly found all icons (and related spacings) greatly increased.
A newly created icon has the same size.
Reboot has no effect.
How can I resize the whole desktop in Ubuntu 18.04?
[image: a clip of my desktop, resized]